# Spring Batch Framework - Auto create Batch Table

Tags: database, spring, spring-batch, privileges, ora-00942

I just created a batch job using Spring Batch framework, but I don't have Database privileges to run CREATE SQL. When I try to run the batch job I hit the error while the framework tried to create TABLE_BATCH_INSTANCE. I try to disable the

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="false">    
 ...
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

But after I tried I still hit the error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Anyway can disable the SQL, I just want to test my reader writer and processor work properly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Spring Batch uses the database to save metadata for its recover/retry functionality.

If you can't create tables in the database then [you have to disable this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

If you can create the batch metadata tables but not in runtime then you might [create them manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775233/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-change-the-spring-batch-meta-data-tables-manually)

Comment: use MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean and ResourcelessTransactionManager disabled the SQL thanks

Comment: Sergio, just a simple question, can I remove/avoid to create those tables ? I am just using spring batch to get data from a table from DB

Comment: Sushi, that's what the first of the options I listed do ("If you can't create tables in the database then...")

Answer (score 70):

**UPDATE:**
As of spring 2.5.0, you should use `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema` instead. See [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.5.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchProperties.java#L79).

---

With Spring Boot 2.0 you probably need this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

By default it will only create the tables if you are using an embedded database.

Or

```
 spring.batch.initialize-schema=never
```

To permanently disable it.

Comment: Just upgraded to Spring Boot 2.5.3 and had a problem with my H2 database + Flyway in test environment ... the manual creation of the BATCH tables was happening twice ... I had to set initialize-schema to `never` ... except the key seems to have now changed: `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never`

Comment: Good to know, I've tried to pinpoint when this changed, but can't find any reference to this new key anywhere in the migration guides or current documentation. I'm curious where/how you've learned it's changed? @Dan

Comment: Hey @pim-hazebroek ... you know I think I let JetBrains' IntelliJ help auto-complete that for me.  I may have looked at the source code too?  I'll get you a definitive answer when I swing back to my project.

Comment: now spring batch uses this property 
`spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always`

Comment: @PrashantSingh do you know since when / which version?

Comment: Don't know about that but today I was using the old property in IntelliJ and it is showing that `spring.batch.initialize-schema=always` is deprecated . So just shared it here .

Comment: Thanks @PrashantSingh I've found the source and updated the answer with additional info to warn future readers.

Answer (score 14):

Spring Batch required following tables to run job

- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ
- BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
- BATCH_JOB_SEQ
- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ

If you are using h2 db then it will create all required table by default

- spring.h2.console.enabled=true
- spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
- spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
- spring.datasource.username=sa
- spring.datasource.password=
- spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

When you start using Mysql or any other database you need to add follwing properties into application.properties

```
               spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I hit the next Error: JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT" not found. I fixed my issue with this, and I'm using h2 db.

Answer (score 12):

Since Spring Boot 2.5.0 use

```
# to always initialize the datasource:
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

# to only initialize an embedded datasource:
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=embedded

# to never initialize the datasource:
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
```

(`spring.batch.initialize-schema` is deprecated since 2.5.0 for removal in 2.7.0)

Comment: this worked for me. replace spring.batch.initialize-schema=always with spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

Answer (score 8):

To enable auto create spring batch data-schema simply add this line to your spring application.properties file :

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always

To understand more about Spring batch meta-data schema :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html

Comment: I was trying to use postgreSQL to maintain the batch schema .This worked for me. THank you.!!!

Answer (score 2):

Seems silly, but someone can have the same problem.

I was receiving this error after drop all tables from a database. When I tried to start the Spring Batch, I received the error:

> bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]

and:

> Invalid object name 'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'

This happened to me because I **drop the tables without restart the service**. The service was started and receive the database metadata **with** the Batch tables on the database. After drop them and not restart the server, the Spring Batch thought that the tables still exists.

After restart the Spring Batch server and execute the batch again, the tables were created without error.

Answer (score 2):

When running with Spring Boot:

`Running with Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.18.RELEASE`

This should be enough:

```
spring:
    batch:
        initializer:
            enabled: false
```

The initialize-schema did not work for this Spring boot version.
After that I was able to copy the SQL scripts from the spring-core jar and change the table capitalization since this was my issue with the automatic table creation under Windows/Mac/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbatch" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>
</beans>
```

And make sure you are using compatible **spring-jdbc** -version with **spring-batch**.
Most probably **spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.JAR** compatible.

Answer (score 0):

`<jdbc:initialize-database/>` tag is parsed by Spring using `InitializeDatabaseBeanDefinitionParser`. You can try debugging this class in your IDE to make sure what values are being picked up for `enabled` attribute. Also this value can be disabled by using JVM parameter `-Dspring.batch.initializer.enabled=false`

Comment: For the CREATE SQL it doesn't show the error so I assumed it is disabled. Just that when I re-run the batch job it prompt me the SQL error again but this time round is related to SELECT SQL.

Comment: Try running "SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = xxx and JOB_KEY =xxx" from database client with the credentials you are using for Spring Batch datasource configuration and see if you have any access issues.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: Spring boot 2.0

```
  batch:
        initialize-schema: never
        initializer:
            enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following setting as the suggested one above has been deprecated:

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

Answer (score 0):

In your DataSourceConfig you should add this code. Once the app comes up it deletes any existing schema , or creates a new one .

```
private DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
      .build();
}
```

If you are not able to do this , the schema scripts are present in your .m2 folder . Run the scripts manually.
Location is inside spring-batch-core jar.

C:\Users\XXX.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\4.3.7.

Split open this jar and find sql schema script you want.

- org\springframework\batch\core\schema-h2.sql.
- org\springframework\batch\core\schema-drop-h2.sql.