# Spring Batch - Problems Connecting to Postgres Database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-batch

Up until now I had been using in-memory H2 DB with Spring Batch. However, now I switched to connecting to external postgres DB. Here was my connection object (with some obfuscation):

```
@Bean
public DataSource postgresDatasource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    datasource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    datasource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:xxxx/blah");
    datasource.setUsername("Joe");
    datasource.setPassword("password");
    return datasource;
}
```

When I start my application, I get:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
> JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?];
> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
> "batch_job_instance" does not exist

I then read that Spring Batch uses the database to save metadata for its recover/retry functionality, and with embedded databases, these are tables Spring Batch sets up by default. Ok, so that would explain why I had never seen this error before.

However, it said I could set this property:

```
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never
```

So I put this in my application.properties file. However, I am still getting the error. I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure spring batch not to auto create batch tables for storing meta data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950551/how-to-configure-spring-batch-not-to-auto-create-batch-tables-for-storing-meta-d)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine , I was able to do something very similar. Although your link was essentially the same approach I ended up answering this myself with the more complete solution in the event that someone might find the details helpful for their own issues in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to address this myself. Ultimately I needed the Spring Batch repository independent from my actual target relational database. So I found this reference:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/342d27bc1ed83312bdcd9c0cb30510f4c469e47d/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/DefaultBatchConfigurer.java#L84

I was able to take the DefaultBatchConfigurer class from that example and make a minor change to the data source by adding the @Qualifier for embedded/local data source:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Then, on my Spring Batch reader (in my other batch config class), I made a minor change to the data source by adding the @Qualifier for postgres data source:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<StuffDto> itemReader(@Qualifier("postgresDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StuffDto>()
    .name("cursorItemReader")
    .dataSource(dataSource)
    .sql(GET_DATA)
    .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(StuffDto.class))
    .build();
}
```

Then lastly (or firstly really as I did these first), I explicitly named my data source beans so java could tell them apart to use as above:

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceContext {


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/test");
        datasource.setUsername("sa");
        datasource.setPassword("");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "postgresDataSource")
    public DataSource postgresDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x:xxxx/blah");
        datasource.setUsername("joe");
        datasource.setPassword("password");
        return datasource;    }
}
```

Once I did all the above, the error disappeared and everything worked.