# Spring Batch with Oracle as JobRepository

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am learning Spring Batch, in the process of creating a POC which would read records from one Oracle schema, process it and update into another oracle schema. The requirement is very simple as it sounds, however I am not finding any good tutorials. I would like to keep Oracle as Spring Batch Job Repository. All the examples online uses H2 DB for Spring Batch Repository and most of them are using xml configuration based, not spring boot.

Questions:

1. Where can I find a good tutorial for Spring Boot 2.3.3 + Spring Batch + Oracle combination.
2. Should the DDL for Spring Batch repository be created by DBAs or the spring batch takes care of it, provided the DB user used to connect to DB has the create table privileges?
3. I followed the example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ with just one change from H2 DB to Oracle DB -
   My pom is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-processing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>batch-processing</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:7501:xe
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=oracle123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
batch.data.source.init=true
```

This user has privileges to create the tables.

Getting an error `Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Just to confirm it is not my Oracle DB error, but something to do with the Spring batch.
I tried running Oracle DB using docker `docker run -d -p 49161:1521 -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g`
& changed my application.properies to

```
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

still same error ```Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

````
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:768) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.isJobInstanceExists(SimpleJobRepository.java:91) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch Framework - Auto create Batch Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249942/spring-batch-framework-auto-create-batch-table)