# Spring Batch Test Failing with error " table BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE not found"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

I am writing a test case to test my `Step` in `spring batch`. Below is my configuration

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BatchTemplateConfig.class,
        CustomerItemWriter.class,BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
@JdbcTest
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBatchTest
public class SampleStepTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Test
   public void testSampleStep(){
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("sampleStep");
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

    }
}
```

Below is my step configuration

```
 @Bean
    public Step sampleStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ItemWriter<Customer> itemWriter, ItemReader<Customer> itemReader) {
        return new StepBuilder("sampleStep", jobRepository)
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();
    }
```

I have tried disabling `@EnableSpringBatchProcessing`(since from spring boot 3, this is not required) and also tried to set the properties
`spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` also changed it to `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never` by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249942/spring-batch-framework-auto-create-batch-table) post. But still I am getting error like below.

```
2023-03-02T16:56:33.198+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] s.g.b.s.SampleStepTest                   : Starting SampleStepTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 5288 (started by  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] s.g.b.s.SampleStepTest                   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-02T16:56:34.277+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 13 ms.
2023-03-02T16:56:34.558+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2023-03-02T16:56:35.048+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:e71d89d7-9684-47e3-9a70-c90803db19d9;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2023-03-02T16:56:36.061+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2023-03-02T16:56:36.491+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-03-02T16:56:36.544+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-03-02T16:56:36.550+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2023-03-02T16:56:36.709+05:30  INFO 5288 --- [    Test worker] s.g.b.s.SampleStepTest                   : Started SampleStepTest in 7.266 seconds (process running for 11.933)

PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:143)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:299)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:390)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy61.getLastJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:111)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:70)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchJob(StepRunner.java:167)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchStep(StepRunner.java:157)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:237)
    at app//org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:187)
    at app//sg.gov.br2s.springbatchtemplate.SampleStepTest.testSampleStep(SampleStepTest.java:37)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42104-214]
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1863)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2334)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2772)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2878)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
    at app//org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at app//org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1637)
    at app//org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    ... 111 more
```

When I try to disable @EnableBatchProcessing I am getting a different error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method sampleJob in com.example.springbatchtemplate.config.BatchTemplateConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: You did not share your datasource configuration.Please share a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a stack trace of the error.

Comment: It seems you are missing the required tables for batch in your test datasource

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine yes it is an embedded data source . I have not made any configurations. But unit tests for my item reader works fine without any configurations.Should I share my reader and writer configs also?I have update the error message with stack trace

Comment: `I have tried disabling @EnableSpringBatchProcessing(since from spring boot 3, this is not required)`: The code above still has that annotation. Are you sure the issue still happens without `@EnableBatchProcessing`? Because with `@EnableBatchProcessing`, Spring Boot v3 will not auto-configure the batch tables.

Comment: When I am disabling the @EnableBatchProcessing I am getting a different error altogether. Tried it just now

Answer (score 4):

From Batch 5, When `@EnableBatchProcessing` is used, the jobLauncherApplicationRunner bean is not created in BatchAutoConfiguration.java
That is because `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is added in version 5.

```java
...
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = DefaultBatchConfiguration.class, annotation = EnableBatchProcessing.class)
....
public class BatchAutoConfiguration {
```

But `@EnableBatchProcessing` should be used to set other datasource and transacionmanager for JobRepository.

Likewise, `BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer`, which initializes data schema, is not created.
As solution, We can create the bean by ourselves.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProperties.class)
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.batch.job", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public JobLauncherApplicationRunner jobLauncherApplicationRunner(
            JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobRepository jobRepository, BatchProperties properties) {
        JobLauncherApplicationRunner runner =
                new JobLauncherApplicationRunner(jobLauncher, jobExplorer, jobRepository);
        String jobNames = properties.getJob().getName();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jobNames)) {
            runner.setJobName(jobNames);
        }
        return runner;
    }
}

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.class)
    BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer batchDataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource,
                @BatchDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> batchDataSource, BatchProperties properties) {
            return new BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer(batchDataSource.getIfAvailable(() -> dataSource),
                    properties.getJdbc());
    }
```

Comment: Works, but it is crazy that now we have to care about this, as @EnableBatchProcessing use is discouraged.

Comment: this answer really saved us.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a correct datasource and scripts to populate your DB.
Something like in your BatchTemplateConfig class:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error as the OP, I'm on Spring framework 5.0, boot 3.0

I removed the annotation
`@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "mssqlDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "mssqlTransactionManager")`

My datasource is configured as a bean elsewhere, but as mentioned by @tasosioan7 it must be configured

Here is my properties for the integration test:

```
spring:
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      platform: h2
    job:
      enabled: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS Schema
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    hikari:
      poolName: ReadHikariPool
      schema: Schema
  jpa:
    database: h2
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Here is most of my very basic test

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("itest")
public class BatchTest {

    @Autowired
    DataSource mssqlDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    @AfterEach
    public void cleanUp() {
        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
    }

    @Test
    public void given_whenStep1Executed_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
        // given

        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(
                "readLastRow");
        Collection actualStepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();
        ExitStatus actualJobExitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();

        // then
        assertThat(actualStepExecutions.size(), is(1));
        assertThat(actualJobExitStatus.getExitCode(), is("COMPLETED"));
    }
}
```